# How do I use sed/regex to find the last multiline match?

Tags: regex, linux, sed

Here's a commands.txt file:

```
START - 'cmd1'
results1a
results1b
results1c
END - 'cmd1'
START - 'cmd2'
results2a
results2b
END - 'cmd1'
START - 'cmd1'
results1d
results1e
results1f
END - 'cmd1'
```

Here's what I have so far:

```
cat commands.txt | sed -n 's/^START - '"'"'(cmd1)'"'"'$/\1/p'
```

And the output is

```
cmd1
cmd1
```

What I want the output to be is

```
results1d
results1e
results1f
```

I haven't figured out how to get multiline matches.

Comment: You regex explicitely captures `cmd1` then uses that as the replacement, that would explain the current behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this line works for your needs:

```
awk "NR==FNR{if(/^START - 'cmd1'/)p=NR;next}FNR>p{if(/^END/)exit;print}" file file
```

you can make the regex more strict, like with `^ and $`, but you got my idea how to handle it.

Comment: Thanks.  Does exactly what it should.  Never thought about using awk.

Answer (score 2):

still can be done in sed, if you prefer.

```
sed -r ':a;$!{N;ba};s/.*START[^\\\n]+\n(.*)\nEND.*/\1/' file

results1d
results1e
results1f
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU):

```
sed '/START/h;//,/END/{//!H};$!d;x;s/[^\n]*\n//' file
```